# Recursive Sed Against Files that Match a Directory Pattern

Tags: bash, shell, sed, sh

Is there an easy way to use `sed` to replace text in files that match a directory pattern? For example, if I had a file called `somedir/example.txt` which contained the following text:

> foobar

I could run the following:

`sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' somedir/example.txt`

Resulting in the text of the file being:

> barbar

Is there a way to specify a directory pattern like:

`somedir/**/example.txt`

Which would recursively update any `example.txt` file under the `somedir` folder? If there is an easier way to accomplish this, I'm game too.

Comment: That should work if you have the `globstar` option turned on.

Comment: See http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option

Comment: Also make sure you're using bash 4.x to get this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have bash version 4, run

```
shopt -s globstar
sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' somedir/**/example.txt
```

If you have an earlier version bash or just a POSIX shell, then run:

```
find somedir -type f -name 'example.txt' -exec sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

For OSX:

```
find somedir -type f -name 'example.txt' -exec sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

#### Documentation

From `man bash` (version 4+):

> **globstar**
>  If  set,  the  pattern  **  used  in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories
>   and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only
>   directories and subdirectories match.

Comment: BTW, it can't be OSX, because its version of `sed` requires an explicit empty string after it, e.g. `sed -i '' -e`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to accept John's answer, however since I figured out a way to do it with perl, while he was writing his answer, I figured I would post anyway:

`find somedir -type f -name 'example.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i -pe 's/foo/bar/g'`

Comment: Very good.  Alternatively:  `find somedir -type f -name 'example.txt' -exec perl  -i -pe 's/foo/bar/g' {} +`

Comment: Whether you use `perl` or `sed` is totally irrelevant. Your question is just about how to find all the files recursively, and what you do with them afterward is orthogonal. So this is basically the same as John's answer.